# Load only basic Packages at the beginning of a session in R

Tags: r

I am facing a problem I have upgraded R from 3.6.3 to 4.0.2 (I also had the newest version 4.1.0 but the problem was the same) and through my scripts I installed all packages on the highest version. However, since that, I am facing the problem that there are quite an amount of packages that are loaded immediately when R started.

```
dput(loadedNamespaces())
c("**zoo**", "tidyselect", "xfun", "shinyjs", "purrr", "corrplot", 
"urca", "lattice", "vars", "colorspace", "vctrs", "generics", 
"usethis", "htmltools", "yaml", "grDevices", "utf8", "rlang", 
"pillar", "glue", "DBI", "forecast", "TTR", "lifecycle", "quantmod", 
"timeDate", "munsell", "gtable", "evaluate", "knitr", "tseries", 
"strucchange", "lmtest", "parallel", "curl", "fansi", "methods", 
"xts", "Rcpp", "scales", "fs", "fracdiff", "ggplot2", "stats", 
"datasets", "graphics", "digest", "stringi", "dplyr", "grid", 
"quadprog", "tools", "sandwich", "magrittr", "tibble", "crayon", 
"pkgconfig", "MASS", "ellipsis", "rsconnect", "utils", "assertthat", 
"rmarkdown", "base", "R6", "nnet", "nlme", "compiler")
```

When I go to the section of packages I do not see the tick that they are loaded as the previous command shows that these packages are active (see zoo example):

[image]

I am quite confused and want to start R only with basic packages. .Rprofile deleted as well as .RData file. So it is not connected with these script files. Could it be a bug? Or do you have any other explanation?

Comment: What is in R_ENVIRON_USER and if you give option --no-environ or --no-init-file  what happens?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am not so experienced, where can I put these commands?

Comment: Try setting packages that you want with this options(defaultPackages=...)                             https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-admin.html#Default-packages

Comment: I still believe you are loading a saved workspace ...

Comment: I tried the adjustment of .Rprofile the packages are loaded, but also the others too. Is there a way how to check if a saved workspace is loaded?

Comment: The .RData file that you deleted was located in the same path that the one given by `getwd()`?

Comment: Try this: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200534577-Resetting-RStudio-Desktop-s-State

Comment: This one for RStudio was really interesting, however, after resetting I saw no difference. Still packages loaded... I am experiencing very similar issue: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/6378

Comment: What exactly do you see in the console when RStudio starts up? if you open the default R GUI instead and run the same command, do you see the same result? Is this your own computer or is it managed by a work IT department?

Comment: This was a really good point :) when I go to the default R only basic packages are loaded. So it must be some issue with RStudio. Yes, it is my own computer.